Habitable Ice belt Planet for fantasy Novel
I've been building a fantasy novel with my brother for quite sometime and when it comes to axial tilt, planetary layout and construction neither of us are experts so I've come to the bright minds here for assistance. Without further delay lets get into what we're trying to achieve.
We want what I've seen described online as an "Ice Belt Planet". A planet where poles are warm and the equator is the cold zone. In our heads the continents on the northern half of the planet circle a sea or ocean (let's call it the North ocean for now.) that sits on the Northern pole. We would like water travel between the land masses that circle the North Ocean to be possible but extremely dangerous and difficult. Its probably obvious but humanoid life needs to be able to exist there and we'd like the areas closest to the North Ocean to be kind tropical zones. Having the continent's being able to support a variety of biomes similar to earth's is important as well.
As far as weather goes we don't want crazy extreme's but interesting weather variations are definitely ok and we'd like a normal-ish seasonal rotation and day and night cycle. We've talked about the idea of having every 4th winter be a terrible one or something along those lines. We like the idea of 2 moons but it's not a requirement.
Currently the other half of the planet is a bit of an after thought. Most of what we've built so far is medieval and prior so their ability to sail and traverse the ice belt wouldn't come till later in our timeline we're thinking but questions or ideas on any of that or anything thing else are greatly appreciated. I look forward to hearing everyone's thoughts and welcome any questions but please bare in mind that I'm by no means an expert in this area. Thank you so much.
Kyle

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

We have a strict one question per post policy on this site. Please [edit] this post to ask a single answerable question about a specific problem you are having, building your world.

Hi @KyleLogan, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Per the [tour], Stack Exchange is not a discussion forum. The [help/dont-ask] states, If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. In other words, if you need help solving a specific problem (one where a single best answer can be chosen), we're golden! If you're looking to generally brainstorm or chat, that's only appropriate in our [chat].

Your question doesn't actually have a question mark in it. What specific problem are you asking us to solve here?

In the mean time, please take a moment to read the three following Help Center pages: [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], and help center. They cover a good 90% of what you need to know to successfully ask questions. Cheers!

@KyleLogan: Hi! Your question got closed recently. I am willing to help you find a fitting question that matches the requirements of WB:SE. I need to know: Are you willing to improve the answer or do you feel you got everything you wanted?

There is a scale of science fiction Hardness.  To oversimplify, "Hard" science fiction is more plausible, realistic, consistent, and scientifically possible than "soft" science fiction.
https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/MediaNotes/MohsScaleOfScienceFictionHardness
Some science fiction writers are content will a very low score on the scale, while others strive for a high score in the scale.
And you describe your story as:

a fantasy novel

And so for a fantasy novel you can be content with a score lower than the scale of science fiction hardness goes, maybe a score of zero or minus one.  But if you want a fantasy novel to have some realism to contrast with whatever magic there many be you can try to make your world as realistic as possible in all the non fantasy aspects.
So you may or may not want to have a scientifically sound reason for your world having warm poles and cold equator.  Each part of that is perfectly possible, and it  is the combination of the two which would be hard to explain.
Part One:  A Cold, Frozen Equator.
It perfectly possible for a world to have a cold, frozen, ice covered equator.  There are many worlds in the other solar which receive only a tiny fraction of the radiation from the Sun that Earth does, and are covered with thick layers of ice not only at the poles, but at the equator and every other region.
And in fact Earth might have been totally covered in ice.

The Snowball Earth is a geohistorical hypothesis that proposes during one or more of Earth's icehouse climates, the planet's surface became nearly entirely frozen with no liquid oceanic or surface water exposed to the atmosphere. The most academically mentioned period of such a global ice age is believed to have occurred some time before 650 mya during the Cryogenian period, which included at least two large glacial periods, the Sturtian and Marinoan glaciations.
Proponents of the hypothesis argue that it best explains sedimentary deposits that are generally believed to be of glacial origin at tropical palaeolatitudes and other enigmatic features in the geological record. Opponents of the hypothesis contest the geological evidence for global glaciation and the geophysical feasibility of an ice- or slush-covered ocean,3 and they emphasize the difficulty of escaping an all-frozen condition. Several unanswered questions remain, including whether Earth was a full "snowball" or a "slushball" with a thin equatorial band of open (or seasonally open) water. The Snowball Earth episodes are proposed to have occurred before the sudden radiations of multicellular bioforms known as the Avalon and Cambrian explosions; the most recent Snowball episode may have triggered the evolution of multicellularity.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowball_Earth

Throughout Earth's climate history (Paleoclimate) its climate has fluctuated between two primary states: greenhouse and icehouse Earth.1 Both climate states last for millions of years and should not be confused with glacial and interglacial periods, which occur as alternate phases within an icehouse period and tend to last less than 1 million years.3 There are five known Icehouse periods in Earth's climate history, which are known as the Huronian, Cryogenian, Andean-Saharan, Late Paleozoic, and Late Cenozoic glaciations.1 The main factors involved in changes of the paleoclimate are believed to be the concentration of atmospheric carbon dioxide (CO2), changes in Earth's orbit, long-term changes in the solar constant, and oceanic and orogenic changes from tectonic plate dynamics.4 Greenhouse and icehouse periods have played key roles in the evolution of life on Earth by directly and indirectly forcing biotic adaptation and turnover at various spatial scales across time.4

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenhouse_and_icehouse_Earth
So it is possible for a planet like Earth orbiting a star like the Sun at the same distance that Earth orbits the Sun - and thus receiving about as much radiation form its star as Earth receives from the Sun, to become very cold and perhaps be covered with ice at the equator.
Part Two: Warm Polar Regions.
Obviously if the luminosity of the star is great enough and/or the planet orbits close enough to the star, it will receive more radiation from the star than Earth Gets from the Sun.  And it should overall be hotter.  If it gets enough radiation from the star and is hot enough, only the polar regions might be cool enough for humans of being with the same temperature requirement and the temperate and tropical regions might be too hot.
Part Three:  Warm Poles, Icy Equator.
And the problem is to combine the warm poles with the icy equator.
To begin with, you might imagine a planet which orbits around its star and has an axis of rotation perpendicular (at a right angle) to the plane that it orbits in. Its equator faces the plane of its orbit while the poles are turned 90degrees away from the orbital plane.  So its axis of rotation is at 90 degrees to the orbital plane.  And thus the axial tilt or obliquity of the planet should be 90 degrees, right?
No, the axial tilt or obliquity of a planet with a rotational axis at 90 degrees to the orbital plane the planet orbits is zero.  And the less the planet's axis of rotation is tilted from the orbital plane the higher its axial tilt is.  The axis of rotation is considered to be titled away from the ideal of being 90degrees from the orbital plane.  So the higher the axial tilt, the closer it is to the orbital plane.
If a planet has an axial tilt of zero degrees, its axis of rotation will be pointed 90 degrees away from the plane the planet orbits in and thus 90 degrees from the direction to the star.  The rays of light from the star will strike the planet in parallel lines.
Since the surface at the the equator is at an angle of 90 degrees to the star, the star is directly overhead at the equator  and the evenly spaced rays of light hit straight down at the equator with the minimum spacing between them.  Thus each photon of light has the smallest possible are to heat up with its energy.
Farther from the equator the ground slants away from the star and thus the parallel rays from the star hit the ground at a slant spaced farther apart.  Each photon of light which hits the ground has a larger area to warm up and so warms it up to a cooler temperature.
And at the poles the light rays come just about parallel to the ground and strike the ground at wide separations.  Thus each photon of light that strikes has a much larger area to heat up and heats up that area to a much colder temperature.
Such a planet would have no seasons.  The temperature would get colder and colder the farther it was from the equator, and it would never get warmer and colder in any one place except for being warmer in the day and colder at night.  Such a planet would have warm equator and cold poles, such light Earth, except that there would be no warm and cold seasons anywhere.  That planet would be the opposite of what you desire.
Part Four:  A Planet with Axial Tilt.
The planet Earth has an axial tilt.  Its axis of rotation is about 23 degrees.  Thus in northern hemisphere summer the north polar region is pointed 90 degrees minus 23 degrees, or 67 degrees, away from the direction to the Sun, and is heated up more and experiences summer. At that time the south polar region is pointed 90 degrees plus 23 degrees, or 113 degrees, away from the direction to the sun, and is heated up much less, and experiences winter.
In northern hemisphere winter the south polar region is pointed 90 degrees plus 23 degrees, or 113 degrees, away from the direction to the sun, and is heated up much less, and experiences winter.  At that time the south polar region is pointed 90 degrees minus 23 degrees, or 67 degrees, away from the direction to the Sun, and is heated up more and experiences summer.
So the polar regions on Earth sometimes get warmer than they would on a planet with zero axial tilt, and experience brief summers.  So that is a little bit closer to what you want.
Part Five:  A Planet With 90 Degrees Axial Tilt.
Among objects in the solar system the axial tits in degrees are:
Mercury 0.03 or 0.01.
Venus 2.24.
Earth 23.44.
Moon 6.68 or 1.54.
Mars 25.19.
Jupiter 3.13 or 3.12.
Saturn 26.73
Uranus 82.83.
Neptune 28.32 or 28.33.
Pluto 57.47 or 60.41.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axial_tilt#Solar_System_bodies
And the large asteroid 2 Pallas has an axial tilt or obliquity of 84 degrees.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Pallas#Orbit_and_rotation
Thus it is possible that your fictional planet could have an axial tilt of about 90 degrees.
In one season the north polar region would be pointed almost directly at the star in the system and would be heated up more than the lower northern latitudes. At he equator the star would be low at the horizon and would give very little heat. The star would be above the horizon all the time in all the northern latitudes.  And the star would be below the horizon in all the southern latitudes which would get very cold.
In the opposite season the south polar region would be pointed almost directly at the star in the system and would be heated up more than the lower southern latitudes. At the equator the star would be low at the horizon and would give very little heat. The star would be above the horizon all the time in all the southern latitudes.  And the star would be below the horizon in all the northern latitudes which would get very cold.
In the two seasons when the planet was a quarter of its orbit between the two above seasons, the equator would be pointed toward and away from the star as it rotated every day and would have alternating day and night.  The poles have the star low on  the horizon all the time.
And there would be four intermediate seasons transitioning between those four extreme seasons.
So it should be possible to figure out which latitudes of the planet receive the most light during the course of a year and thus are overall hottest.  It may be the equator, the temperate zones, or the polar zone.
And if calculations show that the polar zones get more heat and light from the star year round than the equatorial regions that can help to make the equator colder and the polar regions warmer.
I note in such a situation the lengths of night and day would vary widely over the seasons, which may or may not be good for your story and world building.
Part Six: Warm Water, Cold Land.
Earth's poles are colder than the temperate zones and the equatorial regions.
The north pole is over the arctic ocean, the south pole is in the continent of Antarctica.

The Antarctic ice sheet is a continental glacier covering 98% of the Antarctic continent, with an area of 14 million square kilometres (5.4 million square miles) and an average thickness of over 2 kilometres (1.2 mi). It is the largest of Earth's two current ice sheets, containing 26.5 million cubic kilometres (6,400,000 cubic miles) of ice, which is equivalent to 61% of all fresh water on Earth. Its surface is nearly continuous, and the only ice-free areas on the continent are the dry valleys, nunataks of the Antarctic mountain ranges, and sparse coastal bedrock

Earth's other ice sheet is also on land, the Greenland ice sheet.

The Greenland ice sheet is an ice sheet which forms the second largest body of ice in the world. It is an average of 1.67 km (1.0 mi) thick, and over 3 km (1.9 mi) thick at its maximum.[96] It is almost 2,900 kilometres (1,800 mi) long in a north–south direction, with a maximum width of 1,100 kilometres (680 mi) at a latitude of 77°N, near its northern edge.[97] The ice sheet covers 1,710,000 square kilometres (660,000 sq mi), around 80% of the surface of Greenland, or about 12% of the area of the Antarctic ice sheet.[96]

The Greenland ice sheet is an ice sheet which forms the second largest body of ice in the world. It is an average of 1.67 km (1.0 mi) thick, and over 3 km (1.9 mi) thick at its maximum.[96] It is almost 2,900 kilometres (1,800 mi) long in a north–south direction, with a maximum width of 1,100 kilometres (680 mi) at a latitude of 77°N, near its northern edge.[97] The ice sheet covers 1,710,000 square kilometres (660,000 sq mi), around 80% of the surface of Greenland, or about 12% of the area of the Antarctic ice sheet.[96]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_sheet#Earth's_current_two_ice_sheets
Much of the other land in the Artic region is covered with much thinner ice for part or all of the year. Most of the artic ocean is covered with park ice a few feet thick, and the area covered with ice expands in the winter and shrinks in the summer.  And much of the land in the Artic region is ice free for part or all of the year.
The Artic is warmer than the Antarctic because because it has more water and less land. Water is darker than ice so it reflects more light and heat and absorbs more light and heat. Open water next to the Arctic pack ice warms up the nearby water under the pack and causes the pack ice to break up and drift south, thus freeing more water to absorb more heat.
Water retain heat more than rock and soil do, so water at the shores of Arctic lands warms the lands and melt the ice at the shores, thus enabling the bared land to absorb more heat and melt more ice.  Thus there is a lot less Artic ice in the summer than in the winter.
So a good design for you planet would be to have an ocean at the north pole if that is where your character live, with a ring shaped continent warm enough for your characters to live in around the polar ocean, and maybe a ring shaped ocean around the ring shaped continent.  And certainly a large continent all around the equator
so the equator is far from any warming water.
Part Seven:  An Eccentric Orbit for the Planet.
An eccentric orbit for the planet can be combined with a planetary axial tilt to make the equatorial temperatures lower than at the poles.
All astronomical objects in orbits around other objects have elliptical orbits which are sort of oval shaped. If you drew the orbit of the planet Earth would look like a circle because the orbit of the Earth is almost circular and has a low eccentricity.  Because there is very little difference the amount of heat which Earth gets from the Sun when it is nearest and farthest, that has very little influence on Earth's seasons compared to the effect of Earth's axial tilt.  If a planet had a more eccentric orbit the change in distance could exceed the effect of the planet's axial tilt.
Ellipical orbits look oval, but one difference is that the larger object is not at the center of the orbit but to one side.
So if your planet has an eccentric orbit and happens to be closest to the star at the same time the pole where your characters live is pointed at the star, it will make the summer in that hemisphere warmer than the summer in the other hemisphere which will point at the star when the planet is farthest from the star.  Thus the warm are in the other hemisphere will be smaller than the warm are in the hemisphere where your characters live.
Part Eight: Altitude.
On Earth the Polar regions are much colder on average than the equatorial regions.  So the farther from the equator, and the closer to the poles, the more common it is for ground to be covered by seasonal or year round ice and snow.  And the closer to the equator and the farther from the poles, the rarer it is to have seasonal or year round snow and ice on the ground.
The Svalbard archipelago is about 78 degrees north and has sufficient plant live to support species of birds, arctic foxes, reindeer, and polar bears.  It is not covered in snow all year round.  Warm sea currents keep it much warmer than other places at the same latitude.
There are a number of mountains at or near the equator which have temporary  snowfalls, or permanent ice glaciers.
https://www.weatherwatch.co.nz/content/surprising-top-10-places-around-the-equator-that-have-snow-glaciers
The air is a lot thinner high in the mountains.  With fewer air particles per volume of space, there is less heat energy per volume of space.  Thus the air can be cold enough for snow and ice just a couple of miles above tropical rainforests or blistering hot deserts.
So it would be a good idea to have the lands near the poles low lying and many great mountain ranges and high plateaus in the equatorial continent to help make the cold equator and warm poles more reasonable.
Iapetus, an icy moon of Saturn, has a equatorial ridge running three quarters of the way around its equator, and taller than mount Everest. nobody know what made the ridge, but if your world could make such a ridge it would be covered with glaciers which would march down the sides to the lowlands.
Part Nine.  An Oblate Planet.
Planets are basically spherical, pulled together by their gravity.  But all planets spin, and thus they are oblate, a little wider at their equators and than between the two poles.  Earth's polar radius is 6,356.752 kilometers while its equatorial radius is 6,378.137 kilometers.  So sea level at the equator is 21.385 kilometers or 13.288 miles farther from the center of the Earth than at the poles.
The atmospheric density at sea level is the same at the equator as at the poles, so the shape of the atmosphere is as oblate as the surface of the Earth and follows the surface.  Thus a rapidly spinning planet with a more  oblate shape would not have a lower air pressure at the equator than the same planet spinning slower with a less oblate shape.
But one advantage of a rapidly spinning highly oblate planet could be the greater distance to the core at the equator.  Internal heat from the planet's lower regions would have not as far to go to emerge at the polar regions than at the equator.  If the internal was many times greater on that planet than on Earth, getting more at the poles could make them significantly warmer than the equator.
Part Ten: Tidal Heating.
Tidal interactions between a planet and its star and a planet and its moon act to slow the rotation periods of both worlds to the drive them farther apart of eons of time  - or in some cases to pull them closer together.  Those tidal interactions also produce waste heat inside the planet.  The tidal heating combines with heat from decay of radioactive elements to produce the internal heat of a planet.
So one way to increase the internal heat of your world would be to have increased tidal heating due to having a much larger and/or nearer moon than Earth has.  In fact, the planet's moon could be increased in mass until it was more like a binary planet.  Or the moon could be increased in mass until it was many times as massive as the planet, thus making the world the characters live on a moon orbiting a giant planet.
Tidal heating can be important to the temperature of a moon.  Io, a moon of  Jupiter, is a volcanic hell because of excessive tidal heating.  A lesser amount of tidal heating could make a moon too hot to have liquid water on the surface, a runaway greenhouse, and thus make it too dry for life. And a still lesser amount of tidal heating could make a world that otherwise was too cold warm enough for liquid water and for life to exist.
In the last couple of decades there have been a number of scientific articles discussing the potential habitability of exomoons orbiting exoplanets in other star systems.
Here is a link to an article from 2013 "Exomoon habitability constrained by illumination and tidal heating", by Rene Heller and Rory Barnes.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.5323
As the title suggests, Heller and Barnes consider that heat from tidal heating as well as heating from illumination by the star can be an important factor in the temperature and thus habitability of a moon.
In that article Heller and Barnes introduced the concept of "a habitable edge" for a giant planet, a distance that a moon would have to orbit beyond in order to avoid excessive tidal heating.
So if a highly oblate moon has a lot of tidal heating the extra heat emerging at the poles could make the poles much warmer than the equator.
Conclusion.  There have been a few other questions about worlds with cold equators and warm poles at this site.  And as far as I remember I always thought that was just about impossible to have, so it is nice to finally have thought of ways to make that possible.
And you should use the search feature in the black bar above to search for other similar questions and see if they have any good suggestions.
Astrophysicist Sean Raymond has a blog planetplanet where he offers to work on worldbuilding problems.  Perhaps he might want to work out a way for a world to have a frozen equator and warm poles.  And if not, you could always just take one or more of my suggestions and assume it would be sufficient to make the climate you want.

Here is a suggestion:
As long as you do not have other requirements, take our earth as prototype for your world. Meaning, your planet will have similar size, mass, distance to its sun and therefore climate zones that are similar to ours.
With this you can picture climate zones in your world easily: The north is cold and has ice, towards the middle (the equator) the climate gets more temperate, moist and "tropical".
This makes it easy for you in the beginning to keep adding and writing new stuff without worrying about climate and planet layout too much.
Add some optical sugar to your world, like having two moons, a space station or what else you might come up with in your story and want to detail in your writing.
After your solar system has grown a bit more beyond a sun, your planet and its moons, you might want to have us do a "plausibility check" on what you have so far at that point.
Right now, there is only little to analyse here, you know? Just keep writing! Don't get discouraged by anything! Don't think everything must make sense! It just has to make sense to you and your brother in the first place! Everyone else comes after that.
Have fun, Kyle!

I applaude everyone who downvoted the single answer to a question without posting an answer as an alternative.
